# Enfore required fields in TypeScript (and work with var-arg constructor)?

Tags: typescript

Since TypeScript 1.3 doesn't yet have abstract fields, one of the ways to require a field to be set is to put it as a constructor argument.

However, since this version also don't have spread operators, this does not work very well if the child also has to pass a var-arg to the parent. For example:

```
class Parent {
    constructor (required1, required2, ...rest) { //...
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor (...args) {
       super(val1, val2, ???);
}
```

In plain-old JavaScript, this pattern is usually done through slicing and applying `arguments` to the super constructor. However, such workaround does not work as `super` can only be called and not `apply()` on.

Have I missed something? Otherwise, is there any alternatives to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly you need to trick the TypeScript compiler

```
class Parent {
    constructor (required1, required2, ...rest) { //...
        if(required1 == void 0) return;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor (...args) {
       super(undefined,undefined); // make the compiler happy
       Parent.apply(this,[val1,val2].concat(args)) // the actual call  
    }
}
```

I've logged a suggestion to get the TS team input : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1790